minimize window effect like macOS on React Native
Is it possible to achieve the same effect like in macOS where the window is minimized in a "Facric" like way while pulled downwards?
I was able to achieve the minimize while using animation but it won't "fold" the modal view like a fabric, don't know if such animation can be achieved on a React Native app.
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Animated, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, Easing } from 'react-native';

const FabricPullModal = () => {
  const modalPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const modalScaleX = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current; // Scale in X axis
  const modalScaleY = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current; // Scale in Y axis
  const modalSkew = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; // Skew for curve effect

  const handleConfirmPress = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      // Animate modal moving downward
      Animated.timing(modalPosition, {
        toValue: 300,  // Move downwards
        duration: 700,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.42, 0, 0, 1), // Smooth curve-like animation
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      // Animate modal shrinking in X-axis (horizontal shrink)
      Animated.timing(modalScaleX, {
        toValue: 0.1,  // Shrink horizontally
        duration: 700,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.42, 0, 0, 1),
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      // Animate modal shrinking in Y-axis (vertical shrink)
      Animated.timing(modalScaleY, {
        toValue: 0.5,  // Shrink vertically, but less to simulate fabric pull
        duration: 700,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.42, 0, 0, 1),
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      // Animate skewing effect
      Animated.timing(modalSkew, {
        toValue: 1,  // Skew to simulate curving
        duration: 700,
        easing: Easing.bezier(1, 0, 0, 1),
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]).start();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Modal */}
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.modal,
          {
            transform: [
              { translateY: modalPosition }, // Move down
              { scaleX: modalScaleX }, // Horizontal scale
              { scaleY: modalScaleY }, // Vertical scale
              { skewX: modalSkew.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: ['0deg', '0deg'],  // Add the curve effect
                })
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Text>Modal Content</Text>
        {/* Confirm button inside the modal */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleConfirmPress} style={styles.confirmButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Confirm</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  modal: {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center', // Center content inside the modal
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  confirmButton: {
    marginTop: 20, // Add some margin to space it from other content
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default FabricPullModal;

